# Perform deployment of an application on multiple servers through the same Jenkins Job

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration

I'm using [Jenkins CI](https://jenkins.io/) to automate the deployment of my Java application, and I'm currently using the following build configurations on the pom.xml file:

```
<!-- teste1 config -->
<deploy.jboss.teste1.host>192.168.0.1</deploy.jboss.teste1.host>
<deploy.jboss.teste1.port>9999</deploy.jboss.teste1.port>
<deploy.jboss.teste1.user>admin</deploy.jboss.teste1.user>
<deploy.jboss.teste1.password>admin</deploy.jboss.teste1.password>

<liquibase.teste1.database>db_01</liquibase.teste1.database>
<liquibase.teste1.host>192.168.0.2</liquibase.teste1.host>
<liquibase.teste1.user>admin</liquibase.teste1.user>
<liquibase.teste1.password>admin</liquibase.teste1.password>

<!-- teste2 config -->
<deploy.jboss.teste2.host>192.168.0.3</deploy.jboss.teste2.host>
<deploy.jboss.teste2.port>9999</deploy.jboss.teste2.port>
<deploy.jboss.teste2.user>admin</deploy.jboss.teste2.user>
<deploy.jboss.teste2.password>admin</deploy.jboss.teste2.password>

<liquibase.teste2.database>db_02</liquibase.teste2.database>
<liquibase.teste2.host>192.168.0.4</liquibase.teste2.host>
<liquibase.teste2.user>admin</liquibase.teste2.user>
<liquibase.teste2.password>admin</liquibase.teste2.password>

<profile>
    <id>teste1</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${deploy.jboss.teste1.host}</hostname>
                    <port>${deploy.jboss.teste1.port}</port>
                    <username>${deploy.jboss.teste1.user}</username>
                    <password>${deploy.jboss.teste1.password}</password>
                    <name>${backend.deployment-name}</name>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                    <skip>${skipDeployment}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-jar</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>${liquibase.changelog.file}</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>${liquibase.changelog.file}</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://${liquibase.teste1.host}:3306/${liquibase.teste1.database}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</url>
                    <username>${liquibase.teste1.user}</username>
                    <password>${liquibase.teste1.password}</password>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.34</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                       <goals>
                         <goal>update</goal>
                       </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>teste2</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${deploy.jboss.teste2.host}</hostname>
                    <port>${deploy.jboss.teste2.port}</port>
                    <username>${deploy.jboss.teste2.user}</username>
                    <password>${deploy.jboss.teste2.password}</password>
                    <name>${backend.deployment-name}</name>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                    <skip>${skipDeployment}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-jar</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>${liquibase.changelog.file}</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>${liquibase.changelog.file}</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://${liquibase.teste2.host}:3306/${liquibase.teste2.database}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</url>
                    <username>${liquibase.teste2.user}</username>
                    <password>${liquibase.teste2.password}</password>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.34</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                       <goals>
                         <goal>update</goal>
                       </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

And in Jenkins I created two Jobs, one for each profile, and in each Job the following maven command is executed respectively:

```
clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste1
clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste2
```

But I would like to deploy the application on two servers at the same time using the same Job, but so far I have not been able to figure out the method to perform such a task, I already tried the following commands but without success:

```
clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste1,teste2

clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste1 -P teste2

clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste1;clean package jboss-as:deploy javadoc:javadoc liquibase:update -P teste2
```

In all cases the deployment is done only in one server. Every help is welcome. Thanks.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Are you using declarative pipeline, scripted pipeline or simple free style job?  Parallel deployment is mandatory or could be consecutive? Is your Jenkins in the same host of your jboss instances? Are you deploying using maven or executing shell commands?

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering the topic, and answering your questions respectively. 1- I am using a simple freestyle job. 2- Parallel deployment is not mandatory but would be desired. 3- My Jenkins is not running on the same server as JBoss. 4- The deployment is done using a maven command, but anyway I will send an image showing exactly what is done in the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish the task I wish I ended up using the "Post Steps" instructions as shown in the image below. It was not the most elegant solution but worked as expected. If someone has a better solution please share.

[image: Post Steps]